# Gradle and eclipse: Missing jar's while deploy a EAR

Tags: eclipse, gradle, jar, ear, application-server

Every time I want to deploy a Gradle EAR project inside eclipse I have a problem with missing jar's.

My project structure is:

- MyEAR (ear)

  - MyEJB (jar)
  - MyVaadin (war)
  - General (jar)

    - Dependencies: eclipselink.jar, jBCrypt-0.4.1.jar ...

The dependencies of the "General" project are jar files located anywhere in public maven repositories.

If I build the EAR with gradle all is fine. If I look into the EAR file I can find a "lib" directory in which are stored the dependencies Jar's of the "General" project. Also if I deploy the EAR to wildfly all runs like expected.

But if I deploy the EAR project inside eclipse directly to the wildfly server it seems that the dependency jars of the "General" project are missing (because I get some ClassNotFoundExc's of classes of these jar's). I have found a workaround:

1. Download the missing jar's and store it locally
2. Open properties of the EAR eclipse project
3. Open "Deployment Assemply" and adding the stored jar's from 1.

But this work around is not good at all, because if there is a new version of a dependency jar I must update the jar on two places. If I forget to update the eclipse "Deployment Assemply" I have two different versions of my software and may be errors occurs only in productive environment and not inside the eclipse project ... :-(

Whats the correct way to let eclipse packaging the EAR with all needed dependencies like it was described in the gradle build files?

Comment: you're asking all my questions for me ;)   I think the correct approach here is to load run-time dependencies into the app server (glassfish/wildfly/etc).